# Windows Vista virtual machine error : VMware Tools are not running in the guest

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, windows-vista

I have a Windows Vista virtual machine. From a central computer, I'm launching commands on that virtual machines, using the commands `runProgramInGuest` and `CopyFileFromGuestToHost`. Regularly I get the error message `VMware Tools are not running in the guest` but when I verify the virtual machine, I can see the service `VMTools` being running, having a PID, corresponding to the process `vmtoolsd.exe`.

In the event log, I see warnings on a regular basis, saying `Error in the RPC loop: RpcIn: Unable to send.`.

Does anybody know what's going on an how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documented error [here](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2036350) at VMware

We had the same issue with some Vista PC's recently and this hotfix sorted it